# infopath 2007 in sharepoint space above form in print view

Tags: sharepoint, whitespace, margin, infopath

i'm using infopath 2007 forms on sharepoint 2007 web, i would like form to fit on one page. I created print view and set its page margins on bottom and top to 0.3cm (that is minimal possible value). Jet still there is huge gap between page top and form that is taking space on page. You can see it here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/infopathc.png/.

Do you know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

did you try opening the form library pages in sharepoint designer and see what is causing that extra space? I would start there first.... Good luck!